# Laravel checkbox not checking just because changing layout

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, view, controller

Working on Laravel Project, I have two layouts.

1. app.blade.php [see on my git repo](https://github.com/kautsaralbana/ReportManagement/blob/master/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
2. old_app.blade.php [see on my git repo](https://github.com/kautsaralbana/ReportManagement/blob/master/resources/views/layouts/old_app.blade.php)

When I use @extends('layouts.old_app') in my blade file, its working fine like this:
[old_app.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyXvs.gif)

But when I use @extends('layouts.app') in my blade file, the checkbox is gone:
[app.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLwWm.gif)

This is my [Controller](https://github.com/kautsaralbana/ReportManagement/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/RoleController.php):

```
public function create()
{
    $permission = Permission::get();
    return view('roles.create', compact('permission'));
}
```

This is my [View](https://github.com/kautsaralbana/ReportManagement/blob/master/resources/views/roles/create.blade.php)

```
<div class="form-group">
    @foreach($permission as $value)
       <label>{{$value->name}}
          <input type="checkbox" class="name" value="{{$value->id}}" name="permission[]">
       </label>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Sorry for my bad english, I would to say thanks for anyone who can help me.

Comment: Welcome. Please don't post code as images, edit your question and paste the code there. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response, wait a sec.

Comment: Did you check the generated HTML source?

Comment: @Rolf Did you mean like when I press CTRL+U in browser page? It is show same even the layout changed.

Comment: Could it be that your javascript is causing the bug?

Answer (score 0):

I could think in 2 obvious things.

- Permission::get(); does not return any record (maybe you forgot to seed the database, to little info to speculate)
- You got a problem with the html + css, either the template have a error or you are forgetting something like a div.row before the checkbox, try pasting a working set of checkbox inside the view, if you can't see it, try putting it before the @yield('content')

Comment: Point number two.
I already recheck about templates. And yeah you right, I have a problem with the html + css, forgeting something.